# Type conversion of Boolean to Number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was working on type conversion of Boolean values to Number in javascript.

```
console.log(new Number(true));//Prints 1
console.log(+true);//Prints 1
console.log(parseInt(true));//Prints NaN
```

Why is the parseInt is throwing NaN? While first and second case given above are working fine.

Comment: [.parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) function actually only parse `string` variables. Here you're giving a `boolean`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Number` constructor invokes `toNumber` internally which as per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber)

> **Boolean**   - Return 1 if argument is true. Return +0 if argument is
>   false.

Which means `Number(true)` returns 1.

**However**, parseInt invokes `toString` internally and as per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring)

> **Boolean**
>   If argument is true, return "true".
>
> If argument is false, return "false".

Which means `parseInt(true)` -> `parseInt("true")` -> `NaN`

since as per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toint32) again

> 3. If number is NaN, +0, −0, +∞, or −∞, return +0.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 4):

Because `parseInt` expects a string and `'true'` is `NaN`.

From MDN:

> [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
>
> The `parseInt()` function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems).

Answer (score 3):

If you are actually working on number conversions then this table might be very helpful:

[image]